# Parsing a directory tree that is not on my local computer using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, adb

So i'm trying to parse a directory tree but the directory tree is not on my local computer. I was able to do it but the problem is that when I tree to parse a path that has a lot of directories inside of it, it takes a long time to complete the process. I thought that by making my code run on multiple threads that it wouldn't take as long, but i'm having some trouble with where to start for the multi-threading process. I've provided my existing code below. If anyone has any advice please commit.

Thank you

**NOTE**

Some of the code uses pyqt5 to display the directory tree to a ui that I created.

```
def populate_values(self):
    list_of_dir = GenVar.device.shell("ls {} -p | grep \"/\"".format(GenVar.path)).split('\n')[0:-1] # Find all directories in the root path
    while len(list_of_dir) > 0: 
            try:
                dir, parent = list_of_dir[0]
                list_of_dir.pop(0)
            except:
                dir = GenVar.path + list_of_dir.pop(0)
            dir_parent = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
            dir_parent.setText(0, dir[len(GenVar.path):])
            dir_items = self._get_sysfs_nodes(path = dir)
            for item in dir_items:
                child = QTreeWidgetItem(dir_parent)
                child.setText(0, item)
            new_list = GenVar.device.shell("ls {} -p | grep \"/\"".format(dir)).split('\n')[0:-1] # Checking if there are any directories within the current directory
            # If there are any directories clean them up and add them to the list_of_dir list
            if len(new_list) > 0:
                for i, child_path in enumerate(new_list):
                    if child_path[-1] != '/':
                        child_path += '/'
                    new_list[i] = (dir + child_path, dir_parent)
                list_of_dir += new_list
```

**EDIT**

GenVar.device is an adb client. So the directory path is not on a shared computer of my local computer its on an adb server. So the code is running on my local machine but Im communicating with an adb server.

Comment: If you want efficiency then using a shell, `ls` and `grep` as additional child processes when there are perfectly good built-ins within python is not a good start.

Comment: @cdarke what do you mean by built-in functions?

Comment: Those in the standard library that do not run external programs (unlike `ls` and `grep`).  for example https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk

Comment: @cdarke Yeah I saw that function but like I said in my post the directory tree is not on my local computer, so I cant use that function, at least that is my understanding of the function that the directory has to be on your local machine.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what `GenVar` is, you don't explain how the code is running on the other machine, assumed it was a shared drive.

Comment: @cdarke Sorry for not making clear enough. I've edited the post and included what GenVar is.